# How to pass variables in url using codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am passing multiple variables like `window.location.href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>search?result="+state1+"&c="+city1;` instead of `window.location.href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>search/"+state1+"/"+city1;`

Now, the problem is when I define `route` i.e. `$route['search?(:any)'] = "test/search?$1";` after a click on submit button then it shows an error on `search` page and print nothing. So, How can I resolve this issue? Please help me.

view:

```
<script>
    $(".submit").click(function(){
        state1 = $("#state1").val();
        city1 = $(".city1").val();
        window.location.href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>search?result="+state1+"&c="+city1;
    });
</script>
```

controller:

```
public function search($raw)
{
    echo $raw;
}
```

config/route.php

```
$route['search?(:any)'] = "test/search?$1";
```

Thank You

Comment: why don't you use the ajax method in `submit` click to pass variables?

Comment: maybe he wants it in the url for bookmark-ability

Comment: Is there any way to do this `<?php echo base_url(); ?>search?result="+state1+"&c="+city1` @M.Hemant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routing is wrong. No need to route the url for access the `$_GET` values.

Try below code.

Change `$route['search?(:any)'] = "test/search?$1";` to `$route['search'] = "test/search";`

To get it values:

`$this->input->get('result');`

`$this->input->get('c');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
**POST:**

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
 var state1 = $("#state1").val();
 var city1 = $(".city1").val();
 $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    complete: function () {
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('controller/cmethod'); ?>",
    data: ({state: state1 ,city: city1}),
    success: function (data) {
    }
 });
});
```

**GET:**

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
 var state1 = $("#state1").val();
 var city1 = $(".city1").val();
 $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    complete: function () {
    },
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('controller/cmethod/'); ?>"+state1+"/"+city1 ,
    success: function (data) {
    }
 });
});
```

**PHP:**
POST

```
function search(){
    echo print_r($_POST);die;
}
```

GET

```
function search($state,$city){
    echo $state;
    echo $city;
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently what you are doing is sending $_GET Data to the controller, you will need to access the data by using

```
$this->input->get();
```

It is an array so you will automatically get all the variables you've sent.

Alternatively you can send the data via segments as CI3 is designed to work with. In your controller you can pass the parameters as arguments to the function. e.g

```
function search($param1,$param2,$param3){
}
```

Using this method this information can then be access by using your site URL plus the segment of data.

```
www.test.com/index.php/controller/param1/param2
```

You will also need to change your JS code to

```
window.location.href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>search/" + state1 + "/" + city1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to use Get method values like Url parameter,
Please  try this code

Jquery Code

```
     $(".submit").click(function(){
    state = $("#state").val();
    city = $(".city").val();
    window.location.href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>search?state="+encodeURIComponent(state)+"&city="+encodeURIComponent(city);
});
```

Route

```
$route['search'] = "test/search";
```

Controller

```
public function search()
    {
        $state = $this->input->get('state');
        $city = $this->input->get('city');
    }
```